# При изменении цвета блока, border остается под цветом. Как исправить?

Tags: html, css

Поставил блок, цвет - белый, с бордером - черный. Сделал чтобы при наведении курсора цвет менялся на серый. Но при этом бордер остается под цветом. Как сделать, чтобы background покрылся на -1px???

Answer (score 5):

Для этого применяется псевдокласс [hover](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover). Пример:

```
div {
border: black solid 2px;
background-color: white;
}
div:hover {
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: нет, я знаю что для это нужен он. Я точно так же делаю, но он остается под цветом

Comment: покажите код

Comment: все, справился. Как закрыть вопрос?